# how to install multiple versions of tensorflow in the same OS, such as centos 7?

Tags: centos, anaconda

I tried to install tensorflow cpu version and gpu version both.

I have installed tensorflow cpu version in anaconda environment in CentOS 7. At the moment I didn't activate virtual environment but just set $PATH to ~/anaconda3/bin and $PYTHONPATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to anaconda. tensorflow cpu version is working now. python version is 3.6.

I made a virtual environment of anaconda, and installed tensorflow-gpu. But python cpu version was removed because it override tensorflow on the same site of ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow

How can I deal with two versions of tensorflow?

This is quite related with [How to downgrade tensorflow, multiple versions possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749992/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-multiple-versions-possible)

Some additional information is that tensorflow runs python version <=3.6.

Answer (score 0):

In my hacking, there are several python virtual environment techniques. One thing is to use "virtualenv". But when the present python version is 3.7, virtualenv makes only python 3.7 version, you can't change it. Another python version might be installed later inside the env directory such as,(I didn't check this)

```
virtualenv vtf_gpu

source vtf_gpu/bin/activate

pip install python-other-version
```

Otherwise, Conda also can handle this, as Yee wrote in [How to downgrade tensorflow, multiple versions possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749992/how-to-downgrade-tensorflow-multiple-versions-possible)

```
conda create -n vtf_gpu python=3.5

conda activate vtf_gpu

(vtf_gpu) pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta1
```

Conda has some benefits compared to "virtualenv". It can assign python version when making a virtual environment. And it creates venv(vtf_gpu) directory in ~/anaconda3/envs/vtf_gpu while "virtualenv" creates venv at /home.

Without "--ignore-installed", pip install the package at
`~/anaconda3/lib/python3/site-packages`
so it will override the previous tensorflow cpu version. So with "--ignore-installed" all the package will be installed inside venv directory such as
`~/anaconda3/envs/vtf_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Then both versions can be run independently by

```
conda activate venv

conda deactivate
```